# Ask for certain characters from a passphrase/password

Tags: php, mysql

On my login form I am trying to get the user to login with email address, password and ask for certain characters from their passphrase.

I have no idea how to do this can anyone help?

Comment: Why would you do that?  Just have them enter their passphrase!

Comment: Its not my requirement, its my clients

Comment: So how far have you got?

Comment: Tell the client that this does not add any extra security, regardless of what they "think".

Comment: What do you need help with here?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: If user sends his WHOLE password, then what's the point of sending a few letters from the password with it? It is redundant, useless and gives you no extra security.
But if you really want to do it.. loop over those extra characters and for each one check if it's present in passphrase sent. This is really trivial to implement.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make it clear enough, I haven't got anywhere yet, I do not even know where to start.

Comment: @cen: I think he wants the form on the webpage to only ask for certain characters.  So the user won't be entering their entire password.

Comment: @user2149630: For this to work, you'd need to store the passwords in a way that they can be retrieved (encrypted or [*shudder*] plain text), this is usually seen as a bad/unsafe practice.

Comment: Thanks.... I am still non the wiser I am now more confused. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user2149630: Start by creating a form that asks for certain characters from a password.  Then add in having PHP get the characters from the full password and compare.

Comment: This is scary. Either (a) the characters never change (always the 1st, 5th, and 9th), so you have to store a hashed and salted version of those characters (so hash "abc"+salt for the passphrase "all@b0utc@rs!"), or (2) you have to be able to retrieve the plaintext passphrase. Option (1) is silly and is actually less secure; it's obviously easier to guess `abc` than it is to guess `all@b0utc@rs!`. Option (2) is terrifyingly insecure; you should assume your users' personal details and passwords will end up on pastebin. Your client needs to adjust their requirement.

Comment: Is anyone willing to start a conversation on here to help me further?

Comment: @user2149630: That's not really what this site is for.  You should try something yourself, then come back when you are stuck on a specific task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of a string as char array in PHP. This lets you access the n.th characater of a string via `$str[n]`, which is exactly what you are looking for and can also be found reading the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) (Example #9).

Comment: Thanks for this, Is there anyway we could discuss a little further as im pretty new to this sort of coding?

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow is not the place for this. But I know there are many bulletin boards concerning PHP, offering tutorials and the room for a conversation